# Do you use custom classes in your Data Science code?

Tags: python, programming, software-development

After a few years in the field I find myself leaning more and more to a functional, side-effect free, deterministic input-output codeing style.

More or less everything in my work is a function:

```
load_data -> clean_data -> engineer_features -> build_model -> evaluate_model -> ...
```

A few dozen times I've looked to build classes to encapsulate some data & logic, but after a few weeks/months they end up getting refactored into functions (which are eventually put into Dagster/Airflow or similar tools).

I do use "objects" in my work, say pd.DataFrame or RandomForrestClassifier, but whenever I write `class` in my code I get this sinking feeling of "I'll refactor this later"

What's your experience been? Do you find custom classes helpful in data science work?